# Three.js Mesh With Multiple Materials Disappears?

Tags: three.js, blender

I'm trying to load a pretty simple model with two materials (applied per-face) in Three.js exported from Blender.  The issue I'm running into is that with multiple materials applied via the code below the mesh disappears entirely, but I can easily use `materials[0]` or `materials[1]` in place of `materials` and see a solid object.  My export settings from blender along with what it should look like are below and the `json` of the model is visible online [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kt1gw48b/).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your JSON file and it displayed just like your image. Here's the code I used (three.js r83):

```
var mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load('/js/models/cube.json',
    function (geometry, materials) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,
            new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials));
        scene.add(mesh);
    }
);
```

http://www.threejsworld.com/tutorials/working-with-materials-in-threejs

Comment: I think this might be a glitch or an improper setting with the Blender exporter then, which version are you using and what settings did you use?  I had to get around it by splitting a wireframe modified version and a solid version into separate .json files and importing them separately.

Comment: exporter version 1.5.0, blender version 2.77a. Same settings as you. I don't see how Blender or exporter could be the problem if your JSON worked for me, y'know

Comment: I missed the `new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials)` bit when I was reading through the first time (I had nearly identical code aside from that replacing it with `materials` alone.)  Thanks.